# Org-mode export bullet as HTML into specific folder with extra exporting option

Tags: org-mode, org-export, config

I would like to add a extra exporting option to my org-mode export dialog.
this option shall export the data as html to a specific folder.

I want to press C-c C-e to open my export dialog and then choose this extra option. I would also like to have it in a separat Category not within the "Export to HTML" category. In best case I would like to have a new Category with different options for different folders.

Comment: (Not an answer but...) Have you seen org-publish? https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing.html

Comment: Yea I have seen it. But I'm not able to figure out how to use it for my scenario.

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask another question : How do I use org-publish to accomplish «whatever»? (I've used it but am no expert)

Comment: Here is [a wiki](https://bitbucket.org/rustom/vit-projects/wiki/Home)
I'd made for my students. The org [publish setup](https://bytebucket.org/rustom/vit-projects/wiki/orgsrc/pub.el?rev=2e63e6a6aadda0c183da408892959ee24fed6106). Offered with some hesitation since I'm not near an (emacs carrying) machine right now and so likely unable to answer queries   To use you'll have to (1) clone the wiki. (2) make sure you have org-md-loaded (3) Follow instructions bottom of file

Comment: Point (2) should be org-md-publish-to-md or some other suitable publishing function you need

Comment: So I've taken a look at the publishing topic. the thing is it seems (I could be wrong tho) that the current file has to be part of a project to be published. But my intend is not to create a project every time I want to use this function. My intend is to be able to "cut out" certain parts of org files at any given point and store them in a special directory. the source files can be anywhere.